# Licensing issue when adding server to SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, add-item

My Client is adding a WFE Server to their SharePoint Farm. Their current setup is 1 App Server, 1 DB Server.

I have installed SharePoint on the new WFE Server but when I try to add it to the existing Farm I get the error :-

'The current server cannot be joined to this farm because the set of installed products does not match the products installed in the farm.

The license state for the current server doesn't match the farm's license state.'

Convinced they are patched to the same level so followed the advice here to see what licenses are on what servers :-

https://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/sharepoint-2013-installation-error-the-current-server-cannot-be-joined-to-this-farm/

Existing App Server : 
SharePoint Foundation 2013 and 
SharePoint Server 2013

New WFE Server : 
SharePoint Foundation 2013 and 
SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise

Is there any way around this other than flattening the WFE and installing SharePoint Server 2013 ? For example can I activate Enterprise features on the App Server and then add the WFE to the Farm ? What are the licensing implications (if any) of doing this ?

I really don't want to start again unless I have to.

All advise greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing App-Server has a SharePoint 2013 Standard license enabled and you accidentally installed your new WFE-Server with an Enterprise-Key.

Do NOT upgrade the existing App-Server to an Enterprise License. The customer would have to buy Enterprise-CALS for all users. Those are not cheap :-)

You cannot "downgrade" the enterprise-key if installation is completed. If you do not want to start completely from scratch, you could try to uninstall the SharePoint-Binaries from the new WFE-Server via "Add/Remove Programs". Then install again with the correct key.

To be honest: Start again with a fresh server. This will make sure you get a clean installation. This shouldn't cost that much time.

Comment: Thanks MHeld, I appreciate both your time and advice. Dan

Comment: Further to this - I've taken your advice MHeld and we've gone for a fresh server with a clean install.  As much as I didn't want to it made sense to start again. Thanks again.......Dan.